# Algorithm - Find Optimal element of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, median

I have an array of mutually different elements (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n). Every element has associated a positive value (w_1, w_2, ..., w_n). The sum of these positives values is 1.

[image: condition1]

I have to find an Optimal element (x_k), which is:

[image: condition2]

and

[image: condition3]

I find this algorithm:

```
proc OptimalElement(arr[])
 prevs_w := 0
 nexts_w := 0

 for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
 {
   wi := arr[i].w

   nexts_w := 1 - prevs_w - wi

   IF (prevs_w < 0,5 && nexts_w <= 0,5) THEN
     return arr[i]
   ELSE
     prevs_w := prevs_w + wi
   ENDIF
 }
end
```

But this algorithm compare only sum of items which index is i < k and i > k. But I need algorithm that calculate sums of items which x_i < x_k and x_i > x_k.

An Algorithm should have work with O(n) time. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thx for tips.

**Example of input:**

x_i |  1  ;  4  ;  2  ;  3  ;  5
w_i | 0,1 ; 0,2 ; 0,3 ; 0,2 ; 0,2

Comment: One solution is here: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~kalpakis/courses/441-sp03/hws/hw4-sol.pdf

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, and should be migrated to http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect):

1. Select a pivot (randomly would be a good idea)
2. [Partition the array around that pivot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version) according to their *x* coordinates, keeping track of the sum *s* of items you put to the left side of it
3. If *s ≥ 1/2*, recurse into the left side. Else, recurse into the right side

The problem here is the run time is *O(n²)* in the worst case. However, it is *O(n)* on average (assuming the elements are somewhat evenly distributed). There are other [partition-based selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) with deterministic linear time which you can probably adapt in a similar way, but they are more complicated.